# Polynomial Coefficients from Sympy to Array

Tags: sympy

In the below code, L1 simplifies to the transfer function that I want:

```
import sympy as sy
z = sy.symbols('z')
L1 = sy.simplify(((z**2 - 0.5*z + 0.16) / (z-1)**2 ) - 1)
L1
```

[image: output L1]

After this, I manually enter the coefficients for the numerator and denominator as follow:

```
num = [1.5, -0.84]
den = [1., -2., 1.]
```

Is there a way to do this from code?  I'm not sure how to convert the sympy result to something that I can work with again without manually creating the arrays num and den.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `as_numer_denom` to get the numerator and denominator and then `as_poly` and `coeffs` to get the coefficients:

```py
In [16]: import sympy as sy 
    ...: z = sy.symbols('z') 
    ...: L1 = sy.simplify(((z**2 - 0.5*z + 0.16) / (z-1)**2 ) - 1) 
    ...: L1                                                                                                                       
Out[16]: 
 1.0⋅(1.5⋅z - 0.84) 
────────────────────
     2              
1.0⋅z  - 2.0⋅z + 1.0

In [17]: num, den = L1.as_numer_denom()                                                                                           

In [18]: num.as_poly(z).coeffs()                                                                                                  
Out[18]: [1.5, -0.84]

In [19]: den.as_poly(z).coeffs()                                                                                                  
Out[19]: [1.0, -2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: You might want to use '.all_coeffs()' in the case that there are missing powers that you want to show up as having 0 for coefficients: `Poly(2*x+x**3).all_coeffs() ->
[1, 0, 2, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Or to get the whole expression, you could do :

```
from sympy import *
z = symbols('z')
L1 = simplify(((z**2 - 0.5*z + 0.16) / (z-1)**2 ) - 1)
srepr(L1)
```

output:

```
"Mul(Float('1.0', precision=53), Add(Mul(Float('1.5', precision=53), Symbol('z')),
Float('-0.83999999999999997', precision=53)), Pow(Add(Mul(Float('1.0', precision=53), 
 Pow(Symbol('z'), Integer(2))), Mul(Integer(-1), Float('2.0', precision=53), 
Symbol('z')), Float('1.0', precision=53)), Integer(-1)))"
```